# Mysql Skip rows in LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, load, load-data-infile

I want to load a text file that looks like this:

```
11 aaa
22 bbb
# comment
33 ccc
44 bbb
# comment
55 eee
```

I'm using this command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/d:\test.txt' 
INTO TABLE foo 
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ' '
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@'#')
```

And i want to skip row's star with #

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ignore n lines work as you expected.
Documentation says

> If all the lines you want to read in have a common prefix that you want to ignore, you can use LINES STARTING BY 'prefix_string' to skip over the prefix, and anything before it. If a line does not include the prefix, the entire line is skipped. Suppose that you issue the following statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES STARTING BY 'xxx';
```

> If the data file looks like this:

```
xxx"abc",1
something xxx"def",2
"ghi",3
```

> The resulting rows will be ("abc",1) and ("def",2). The third row in the file is skipped because it does not contain the prefix.
>
> The IGNORE number LINES option can be used to ignore lines at the start of the file. For example, you can use IGNORE 1 LINES to skip over an initial header line containing column names:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I think your best shot will be clearing input text before loading file.